# How high are the chances of getting a legendary card?

Tags: hearthstone

So I got a normal Deathwing in the 3rd card package I opened, and since I usually am like the unluckiest person when it comes to Blizzard games I asked myself what the chances of getting a legendary card are.

Is it compareable to the Dropchances of a certain Epic in let's say WoW (or 'insert Blizzard game' here) or is there even a special percentage per package? How many packages do you normally have to open to get one of these shiny orange cards?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to what most people that opened a lot of packs said, there's quite a  low chance of getting a legendary.

On average, people get 1 legendary per 20-25 packs. Some are less fortunate than that however.

*Source*: [S1](http://www.hearthpwn.com/forums/hearthstone-general/theorycrafting/398-cards-rarity-chances-on-packs), [S2](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/forum/topic/11041384236), [S3](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/forum/topic/10972927765)

Comment: I have opened 79 packs from 79 arenas and have only opened 1 legendary so far.  It happens.

Comment: I'm a newbie player - I've started playing only recently and I've opened perhaps 7 or so packs. I got 2 legendaries thus far.

Comment: @Shaamaan Go play lottery! So far I only managed to get 1 epic card, no legenderies for me yet. I am jelly!

Comment: @ChrisHateZ No need to be. While one legendary is indeed good (Lord Jaraxxus) it's only useful for warlocks (and their class-specific cards kind of suck) while the other is so so on it's own (Baron Geddon). Getting a legendary on it's own is one thing. Getting the legendary you WANT or NEED is another thing altogether. Try [THIS](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/138791/usage-of-baron-geddon) on for size... a GOLDEN legendary - meaning the guy can change the card to any other legendary of their choosing.

Comment: it seems the chance has been doubled after open beta

Comment: I have got a golden legendary (baron geddon, immediately converted to Ysera) at my 15th-ish. I guess I got too lucky. Just do not farm and hope for legendaries, they just come and surprise you:)

Comment: While the chances are very low, random is still random. I've gotten two legendaries in one pack: http://bit.ly/1dveWxH

Comment: My is new and opened around 10 packs, he got antonaidis, tirion fordring and tinkmaster over-spark. I am playing since closed beta and opened well over a hunderd packs and I got cairne bloodhoof, bloodmage thalnos and baron gedeon. It's all about the rng

Comment: Is kind a annoying playing normal game and almost win the game then the other players use his 2/3 legendary to turn the game. Almost every people who win me have more than 1 legendary and I can't have one of those incredible cards :'(

Comment: Yeah I know Lucas. That's why I don't play Hearthstone so much anymore, I play it very rarely now. People that put a lot of money in the game will have HUGE advantage because of those legendaries. The game is pay to win.

Comment: @ChrisHateZ I strongly disagree with that sentiment.  There's a lot of streamers that show themselves getting to Legend rank on a free-to-play account.  A lot of the most competitive decks only have 1-2 legendaries, and it's easy to get very far without any.  Also, you can jump into the arena for an even playing field - which also tends to be the best way to get gold and cards.  It's "Play skillfully to win", not "Pay to win"

Comment: I just had 2 legendaries and an epic card in one pack, I thought I was imagining it